# Azure - Virtual Application deployment overwrites root application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I'm trying to create Azure deployment of three applications (App Service with Virtual Applications). The structure should be as follows:

```
/app-1
/app-2
/
```

Where the 3-rd application is contained in the root, containing some static files (index.html, Web.config).

For the goal I've created 2 release pipelines:

1. Deploying **app-1** and static files to root
2. Deploying **app-2**

When I run the **app-2** pipeline and then the **app-1** & **tatic files** pipeline, everything works as expected. However, when the **app-2** pipeline is ran last, the root (3-rd application) is purged, even that it's configured to deploy only to the corresponding virtual application.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Found a workaround. All of the Deploy Azure App Service tasks were added Additional Deployment Options - Web Deploy, Preserve files.

The same command was executed as before, however it seems to have effect.

Comment: By default, your deployment happens to the root application in the Azure Web App. If you want to deploy to a specific virtual application, enter its name in the Virtual Application property of the Azure App Service Deploy task.

Note that each app has the default root path (/) mapped to D:\home\site\wwwroot, where your code is deployed by default. If your app root is in a different folder, or if your repository has more than one application, you can edit or add virtual applications and directories.

Comment: Yes, I'm using virtual applications, as stated above. And the release pipelines have virtual application configuration.

Answer (score 1):

#### Workaround

Change task version to 3.
(There is 1 important change between 3<->4 - packageForLinux for version 3 is not alias for Package as it is in v4)

input json (it is not clear from readme what are inputs names): https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV3/task.json

readme: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV3/README.md

More info in this github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13946

---

I also had the same issue during last days and I finally found workaround. Not desired one but it works at least.

---

For me workaround with web deploy was not working properly as my app was rewriting root with app files from old deploy. (O_o)

This issue is very similar to my issue so that's why I left here another workaround.